# About an exception handling in 《Head First Python》

Tags: python

In Python, code debugging tries to open a file and read it. Currently I create a folder with the same name as the file in the code directory to replace this file. Why not display the traceback trace message (IsADirectoryError exception), but display the except code group catches the exception and processes it directly(About exception handling of PermissionError).

E.g:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSw4Y.png)

And then this is the information found in the official python documentation:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oRLQ.png)

Comment: What does 《Head First Python》mean anyway?

Comment: That is book for beginners.

Comment: Well… what *are* the permissions on that directory?

Comment: I am a Python beginner.

Answer (score -1):

You're catching the exception and simply printing the message.

If you want to expose the exception itself you need to do something similar to the following with the error object:

```
except PermissionError as e:
 print str(e)
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.Then I mean, I deleted the file “myfile.txt” and replaced it with a folder called myfile.txt.Why does the compiler not report the IsADirecoryError exception(IsADirecoryError exception is caused by an exception when the directory request file operation is performed.) ,but use the PermissionError exception handler to handle my exception operation. (PermissionError exception is caused by an exception in the file permission operation.)